# Mongoose doesn't seems to publish after deepSleep

Tags: mongoose, mqtt

I'm using an ESP32 HiGrow Plant sensor board.

I've slightly touched this firmware : https://github.com/lucafabbri/HiGrow-Mongoose-OS-Firmware/blob/master/fs/init.js

To make it publish the sensors data via MQTT instead of HTTP.

I'm using my own mosquitto instance.

With those changes I can successfully publish every 5 seconds:

```
if (deviceId !== "" && connected) {
    GPIO.write(statusLightPin, 0);
    let higrowData = {'DeviceId': deviceId, 'Temperature': t, 'Humidity': h, 'Moisture': m};

    let higrowData = JSON.stringify({
      DeviceId: deviceId,
      Temperature: t,
      Humidity: h,
      Moisture: m
    });

    let topic = 'devices/' + Cfg.get('device.id') + '/events';

    let ok = MQTT.pub(topic, higrowData, 1);
    print('Published:', ok, topic, '->', higrowData);

    GPIO.write(statusLightPin, 1);
} else {
    print("DeviceId:",deviceId,"Connected:",connected);
    GPIO.write(statusLightPin, 1);
}
```

But as soon as I try to deepSleep after a successful publish, the device goes to sleep but doesn't publish...

```
if (deviceId !== "" && connected) {
    GPIO.write(statusLightPin, 0);
    let higrowData = {'DeviceId': deviceId, 'Temperature': t, 'Humidity': h, 'Moisture': m};

    let higrowData = JSON.stringify({
      DeviceId: deviceId,
      Temperature: t,
      Humidity: h,
      Moisture: m
    });

    let topic = 'devices/' + Cfg.get('device.id') + '/events';

    let ok = MQTT.pub(topic, higrowData, 1);
    print('Published:', ok, topic, '->', higrowData);

    if (ok) {
      print('Success! Going to sleep');
      ESP32.deepSleep(15000000); // 15 seconds 
    } else { 
      print('MQTT error');
    }

    GPIO.write(statusLightPin, 1);

} else {

    print("DeviceId:",deviceId,"Connected:",connected);
    GPIO.write(statusLightPin, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hit the same problem. The MQTT call must be asynchronous, so the deep sleep is cutting it off before it can complete.

We can use the event handler to get acknowledgement of the publish/s from the MQTT broker before putting the device into deep sleep. 
I relies on QOS being set to 1 to receive the acknowledgement.
This is the same concept as Dirks answer

Here is what I came up with. The full project is available here: https://gitlab.com/PseudoNet/higrow-sensor

```
...
let isConnected = false;
let hasPublished = false;
let qos = 1;//Must be set to 1  

function publishData() {

  let higrowdata = { deviceId: Cfg.get('higrow.id'), temperature: dht.getTemp(), humidity: dht.getHumidity(), water: ADC.read(SOILpin) };
  Log.print(Log.INFO, JSON.stringify(higrowdata));

  if (MQTT.pub('higrow/' + higrowdata.deviceId + '/temperature', JSON.stringify(higrowdata.temperature), qos)
    && MQTT.pub('higrow/' + higrowdata.deviceId + '/humidity', JSON.stringify(higrowdata.humidity), qos)
    && MQTT.pub('higrow/' + higrowdata.deviceId + '/water', JSON.stringify(higrowdata.water), qos)) {
    Log.print(Log.INFO, 'Payload sent');
    hasPublished = true;
  }
}


//Wait for mqtt server connection
Timer.set(10000, Timer.REPEAT, function () {
  if (isConnected) {
    Log.print(Log.DEBUG, 'Poll Connected');
    publishData();
  } else {
    Log.print(Log.DEBUG, 'No connecion...waiting');
  }
}, null
);

MQTT.setEventHandler(function (conn, ev) {
  if (ev !== 0) {
    let evs = '?';
    if (ev === MQTT.EV_CONNACK) {
      evs = 'CONNACK';   // Connection to broker has been established
    } else if (ev === MQTT.EV_PUBLISH) {
      evs = 'PUBLISH';   // msg published to topics we are subscribed to
    } else if (ev === MQTT.EV_PUBACK) {
      evs = 'PUBACK';    // ACK for publishing of a message with QoS&amp;gt;0
    } else if (ev === MQTT.EV_SUBACK) {
      evs = 'SUBACK';    // ACK for a subscribe request
    } else if (ev === MQTT.EV_UNSUBACK) {
      evs = 'UNSUBACK';  // ACK for an unsubscribe request
    } else if (ev === MQTT.EV_CLOSE) {
      evs = 'CLOSE';     // connection to broker was closed
    }
    Log.print(Log.DEBUG, 'MQTT event:' + evs);
    if (ev === MQTT.EV_CONNACK) {
      Log.print(Log.DEBUG, 'MQTT Connected');
      isConnected = true;
      publishData();
    } else if (ev === MQTT.EV_PUBACK) {
      if (hasPublished) {
        Log.print(Log.INFO, 'MQTT publish confirmed... init deep sleep');
        ESP32.deepSleep(Cfg.get('higrow.interval_min')*60000000);
      }
    }
  }
}, null);
```

Comment: Please edit this answer to include the gist of the solution. Link only answers become useless if the link break.

Answer (score 0):

```
  let ok = 1;
  MQTT.setEventHandler(function(conn, ev ,edata) {
    print ('MQTT event handler: connect', ev);
    if (ev === 0) {
    ok = MQTT.pub(topic, higrowData, 1);
    print('Published:', ok, topic, '->', higrowData);
    } else { 
      print('error');
    }
  }, null);
  MQTT.setEventHandler(function(conn, ev ,edata) {
    print ('MQTT event handler: write', ev);
    if (ev === 204) {
      print('Success! Going to sleep');
      ESP32.deepSleep(120000000); // 120 seconds
    }  
  }, null);
```

Comment: Please edit this answer to include some context to the code